# Duplicate Javascript Output

Tags: javascript, browser, output

I'm trying to start a new script. Right now the code is very simple. I was just wanting to test the setInterval() logic, but then I noticed my output keeps duplicating.

Here's my script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    console.log('test');

    setInterval(function(){console.log('interval')}, 5000);//5 seconds
});
```

Like I said, simple.

The way I understand this, I expect the output on the console to be:

```
test 
interval
interval 
interval 
...
```

...with 'interval' repeating once every 5 seconds.

But I'm actually getting:

```
test
test
interval
interval
interval
interval
...
```

...with 'interval' being posted to the console TWICE every 5 seconds!

I'm completely confused as to why I'm getting the duplicate output. Anybody know how to stop this duplication I'm experiencing?

Comment: Sounds like you ran your dom-ready code twice - you also got `test` twice.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the same but am getting console as expected, please verify console in this code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log('test');

    setInterval(function(){console.log('interval')}, 5000);//5 seconds
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to Tampermonkey.  I disabled it and used Greasemonkey and had no problems. Thanks for the replies.